# Shows " Uncaught ReferenceError : form is not defined " in the console

Tags: javascript, html

I am a complete beginer, and I am learning frontend web development currently. And as a first project I was creating a simple calculator. I followed steps from a youtuber as I was learning from him. But the problem occuring is that whenever I am clicking buttons it is not displaying the number in the display bar and showing me error **"Uncaught ReferenceError : form is not defined"**. I currently don't have any knowledeg regarding this pls help me out. I am just curious that what is my mistake.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>   
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form">
            <div class="display">
                <input name="displayResult" type="text" placeholder="0" />
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="row">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="b7" value="7" onclick="func(b7.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="b8" value="8" onclick="func(b8.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="b9" value="9" onclick="func(b9.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="plus" value="+" onclick="func(plus.value)">
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="b4" value="4" onclick="func(b4.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="b5" value="5" onclick="func(b5.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="b6" value="6" onclick="func(b6.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="minus" value="-" onclick="func(minus.value)">
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="b1" value="1" onclick="func(b1.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="b2" value="2" onclick="func(b2.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="b3" value="3" onclick="func(b3.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="mul" value="*" onclick="func(mul.value)">
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="b0" value="0" onclick="func(b0.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="bd" value="." onclick="func(bd.value)">
                    <input class="btn" type="button" name="divv" value="/" onclick="func(divv.value)">
                    <input class="equal" type="button"  value="=" onclick="displayResult.value=eval(displayResult.value)">
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        function func(result) {
            form.displayResult.value = form.displayResult.value + result;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

in the console that error is being showed for this specific line,

```
    form.displayResult.value = form.displayResult.value + result;
```

Comment: Why do you expect that there is an object with the name `form`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have not defined your `form` variable. In javascript all undeclared variables have a value of `undefined`.

To fix this, inside your `func`, just add `var form = document.getElementByClassName('form')[0]`.

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: _"In javascript all undeclared variables have a value of undefined"_ - No, they just don't exist, hence the `ReferenceError`

Comment: I guess I wanted to sat all un-initiated variables have value of undefined

Answer (score 0):

form means nothing to javascript. Therefore, it is not defined. You need to fetch the form in the `DOM` first:

```
const form = document.querySelector("form.form");
// would be safer if you gave the form an id but doesn't matter in this case

// then you can change the value
form.displayValue.value += result;
```

a quick look at [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 0):

Add `let form = document.getElementById('form')` in `func()`:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

    <head>
      <title>Calculator</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <form class="form" id="form" )>
          <div class="display">
            <input name="displayResult" type="text" placeholder="0" />
          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <div class="row">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="b7" value="7" onclick="func(b7.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="b8" value="8" onclick="func(b8.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="b9" value="9" onclick="func(b9.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="plus" value="+" onclick="func(plus.value)">
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="b4" value="4" onclick="func(b4.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="b5" value="5" onclick="func(b5.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="b6" value="6" onclick="func(b6.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="minus" value="-" onclick="func(minus.value)">
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="b1" value="1" onclick="func(b1.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="b2" value="2" onclick="func(b2.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="b3" value="3" onclick="func(b3.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="mul" value="*" onclick="func(mul.value)">
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="b0" value="0" onclick="func(b0.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="bd" value="." onclick="func(bd.value)">
              <input class="btn" type="button" name="divv" value="/" onclick="func(divv.value)">
              <input class="equal" type="button" value="=" onclick="displayResult.value=eval(displayResult.value)">
            </div>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <script>
        function func(result) {
          let form = document.getElementById('form')
          form.displayResult.value = form.displayResult.value + result;
        }

      </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your `<form>` doesn't have an `id` or `name` attribute.

---

If you want to access your elements without querying the DOM like the given code, you should give your element an `id` or `name` attribute, then it becomes a property of `window` (a global variable) and you can directly access it from JavaScript.

---

```js
function func(result) {
  console.log(form);
  form.displayResult.value = Number(form.displayResult.value) + Number(result);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="form" class="form">
    <div class="display">
      <input name="displayResult" type="text" placeholder="0" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="row">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="b7" value="7" onclick="func(b7.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="b8" value="8" onclick="func(b8.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="b9" value="9" onclick="func(b9.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="plus" value="+" onclick="func(plus.value)">
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="b4" value="4" onclick="func(b4.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="b5" value="5" onclick="func(b5.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="b6" value="6" onclick="func(b6.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="minus" value="-" onclick="func(minus.value)">
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="b1" value="1" onclick="func(b1.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="b2" value="2" onclick="func(b2.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="b3" value="3" onclick="func(b3.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="mul" value="*" onclick="func(mul.value)">
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="b0" value="0" onclick="func(b0.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="bd" value="." onclick="func(bd.value)">
        <input class="btn" type="button" name="divv" value="/" onclick="func(divv.value)">
        <input class="equal" type="button" value="=" onclick="displayResult.value=eval(displayResult.value)">
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

P.S:

- I'm not saying this is a good practice, just sharing how it works.
- Also `value` attribute returns a `string`, you should convert them to
  `number` in order to perform mathematical operations.
- Your result input doesn't have a default value (`placeholder="0"` isn't the same as `value="0"`), you should set it as 0 or handle the empty string value in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

`form` isn't defined here. What you need to do is get the input field as an object and change it's text.

```js
function func(result) {
  let input = document.getElementById("input-field");
  input.value += result;
}
```

Before this, add an `id` to your `input` tag: " `"input-field"`.